# How to access a past transaction's status in Global Payments PHP API?

Tags: payment-gateway, global-payments-api

After having authorized a transaction successfully,  I want to query the same transaction from time to time (using the global payments order or transaction id) and check for any changes in its status so that I can update the status in my own database.

There is the option to fetch a list of all deposited or disputed transactions through the api (found in "settlement reporting" section of documentation) but:

- First: I don't want to search through a list of all time transactions just for a single record so it is not an efficient solution
- Second: This option only returns settled transactions - so all other transactions (including REFUNDED, REBATED, AUTHORIZED ,etc...) are excluded.

I can't find any curl request in the documentations to achieve this. So I was wondering if there is any way to achieve this?
I'm using the PHP library.